# The settings of a java experiment in google cloud?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

OK. I am developing a complex console-based java application. I edit the code (using NetBeans) from my lab or home computers. Everything is synched through dropbox.

Now I'm planning to get Google Cloud into the loop. That is, runs the java program through Google Compute Engine (or any other GC powerful machines). I used GCE for a couple of months and ran into the following problems:

- I need to re-upload the code to GCE every time I change it in one computer.
- There is no IDE that I can use on Google Cloud. This means `vim` is my un-welcomed friend.

This makes the GCE choice very hard and was looking for the optimal settings (services to subscribe, apps to downloads) that would eliminate those two problems.

Comment: uou could just install dropbox on gce.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using your GCE instance as development environment, install a [desktop environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment) on your Linux VM and use your NetBeans IDE and as Zig said just install Dropbox on your GCE instance to synchronize your codes with your other machines.